# Fix query to resolve to_char and or string comparison issue in scala databricks 2.4.3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've processed parquet file and created the following data frame in scala spark 2.4.3.

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|     itemno|requestMonth|requestYear|totalRequested|requestDate|
+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|    7512365|           2|       2014|         110.0| 2014-02-01|
|    7519278|           4|       2013|          96.0| 2013-04-01|
|5436134-070|          12|       2013|           8.0| 2013-12-01|
|    7547385|           1|       2014|          89.0| 2014-01-01|
|    0453978|           9|       2014|          18.0| 2014-09-01|
|    7558402|          10|       2014|         260.0| 2014-10-01|
|5437662-070|           7|       2013|          78.0| 2013-07-01|
|    3089858|          11|       2014|           5.0| 2014-11-01|
|    7181584|           2|       2017|           4.0| 2017-02-01|
|    7081417|           3|       2017|          15.0| 2017-03-01|
|    5814215|           4|       2017|          35.0| 2017-04-01|
|    7178940|          10|       2014|           5.0| 2014-10-01|
|    0450636|           1|       2015|           7.0| 2015-01-01|
|    5133406|           5|       2014|          46.0| 2014-05-01|
|    2204858|          12|       2015|          34.0| 2015-12-01|
|    1824299|           5|       2015|           1.0| 2015-05-01|
|5437474-620|           8|       2015|           4.0| 2015-08-01|
|    3086317|           9|       2014|           1.0| 2014-09-01|
|    2204331|           3|       2015|           2.0| 2015-03-01|
|    5334160|           1|       2018|           2.0| 2018-01-01|
+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

To derive a new feature, I am trying to apply logic and rearrange data frame as following

```
itemno – as it is in above-mentioned data frame

startDate - the start of the season

endDate - the end of the season

totalRequested - number of parts requested in that season

percetageOfRequests - totalRequested in current season / total over this plus 3 previous seasons (4 total seasons)

//seasons date for reference
Spring: 1 March to 31 May.

Summer: 1 June to 31 August.

Autumn: 1 September to 30 November.

Winter: 1 December to 28 February.
```

**What I did:**

I tried following two logics

```
case 
            when to_char(StartDate,'MMDD') between '0301' and '0531' then 'spring'
           .....
           .....
           end as season
```

but it didn't work. I did to_char logic in oracle DB and it worked there but after looking around, I found spark SQL doesn't have this function. Also, I tried

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val dateDF1 = orvPartRequestsDF.withColumn("MMDD", concat_ws("-", month($"requestDate"), dayofmonth($"requestDate")))

%sql
select distinct requestDate, MMDD, 
case 
           when MMDD between '3-1' and '5-31' then 'Spring' 
           when MMDD between '6-1' and '8-31' then 'Summer' 
           when MMDD between '9-1' and '11-30' then 'Autumn' 
           when MMDD between '12-1' and '2-28' then 'Winter'
 end as season
from temporal
```

and it also didn't work. Could you please let me know what I am missing here *(my guess is I can't compare strings like this but I am not sure so I asked here)* and how I can solve this?

**After JXC solution#1 with range between**

Since I was seeing some dicrepancy, I am sharing data frame again. Following is the dataframe `seasonDF12`

```
+-------+-----------+--------------+------+----------+
| itemno|requestYear|totalRequested|season|seasonCalc|
+-------+-----------+--------------+------+----------+
|0450000|       2011|           0.0|Winter|    201075|
|0450000|       2011|           0.0|Winter|    201075|
|0450000|       2011|           0.0|Spring|    201100|
|0450000|       2011|           0.0|Spring|    201100|
|0450000|       2011|           0.0|Spring|    201100|
|0450000|       2011|           0.0|Summer|    201125|
|0450000|       2011|           0.0|Summer|    201125|
|0450000|       2011|           0.0|Summer|    201125|
|0450000|       2011|           0.0|Autumn|    201150|
|0450000|       2011|           0.0|Autumn|    201150|
|0450000|       2011|           0.0|Autumn|    201150|
|0450000|       2011|           0.0|Winter|    201175|
|0450000|       2012|           3.0|Winter|    201175|
|0450000|       2012|           1.0|Winter|    201175|
|0450000|       2012|           4.0|Spring|    201200|
|0450000|       2012|           0.0|Spring|    201200|
|0450000|       2012|           0.0|Spring|    201200|
|0450000|       2012|           2.0|Summer|    201225|
|0450000|       2012|           3.0|Summer|    201225|
|0450000|       2012|           2.0|Summer|    201225|
+-------+-----------+--------------+------+----------+
```

to which I'll apply

```
val seasonDF2 = seasonDF12.selectExpr("*", """
                                      sum(totalRequested) OVER (
                                          PARTITION BY itemno
                                          ORDER BY seasonCalc
                                          RANGE BETWEEN 100 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                                      ) AS sum_totalRequested

                                   """)
```

and I am seeing

[image]

look at first 40 in `sum_totalRequested column`. All the entries above it are 0. Not sure why it's 40. I think I already shared it but I need above dataframe to be transformed in to

```
itemno  startDateOfSeason  endDateOfSeason   sum_totalRequestedBySeason  (totalrequestedinCurrentSeason/totalRequestedinlast 3 + current season.)
```

**Final output will be like this:**

```
itemno  startDateOfSeason  endDateOfSeason     season      sum_totalRequestedBySeason  (totalrequestedinCurrentSeason/totalRequestedinlast 3 + current season.)
123     12/01/2018          02/28/2019         winter       12                          12/12+ 36 (36 from previous three seasons)
123     03/01/2019          05/31/2019         spring       24                          24/24 + 45 (45 from previous three seasons)
```

Comment: remove the day, just use month, i.e. `month(startDate) in (3,4,5) then 'Spring'` etc.

Comment: @jxc: It'll work in this case but I was wondering what if I need MMDD to be checked ```e.g. MMDD between 02-15 and 03-15 then ...```. I was confused there so I asked it. Also in ```percetageOfRequests denominator which is total over this plus 3 previous seasons (4 total seasons)```, I was using little complex logic of looking at year and seasons to get last 3 three seasons and then add it to current season and then divide. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I think you just need to process the season which across the year differently, putting year and season as named_struct is an easy fix to keep both information, so that you can filter/group DataFrame rows much easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit-2:** adjusted to calculate the sum groupby seasons first and then the Window aggregate sum:

**Edit-1:** Based on the comments, the named season is not required. we can set `Spring`, `Summer`, `Autumn`, `Winter` as `0`, `25`, `50` and `75` respectively and the season will be an integer added up by `year(requestDate)*100` so that we can use rangeBetween (offset=-100 for current + the previous 3 seasons) in Window aggregate functions:

Note: below are *pyspark* code:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_table")

df1 = spark.sql("""
    WITH t1 AS ( SELECT *
                 , year(requestDate) as YY
                 , date_format(requestDate, "MMdd") as MMDD 
                 FROM df_table )
       , t2 AS ( SELECT *,
       CASE
         WHEN MMDD BETWEEN '0301' AND '0531' THEN
           named_struct(
               'startDateOfSeason', date(concat_ws('-', YY, '03-01'))
             , 'endDateOfSeason', date(concat_ws('-', YY, '05-31'))
             , 'season', 'spring'
             , 'label', int(YY)*100
           )
         WHEN MMDD BETWEEN '0601' AND '0831' THEN
           named_struct(
               'startDateOfSeason', date(concat_ws('-', YY, '06-01'))
             , 'endDateOfSeason', date(concat_ws('-', YY, '08-31'))
             , 'season', 'summer'
             , 'label', int(YY)*100 + 25
           )
         WHEN MMDD BETWEEN '0901' AND '1130' THEN
           named_struct(
               'startDateOfSeason', date(concat_ws('-', YY, '09-01'))
             , 'endDateOfSeason', date(concat_ws('-', YY, '11-30'))
             , 'season', 'autumn'
             , 'label', int(YY)*100 + 50
           )
         WHEN MMDD BETWEEN '1201' AND '1231' THEN
           named_struct(
               'startDateOfSeason', date(concat_ws('-', YY, '12-01'))
             , 'endDateOfSeason', last_day(concat_ws('-', int(YY)+1, '02-28'))
             , 'season', 'winter'
             , 'label', int(YY)*100 + 75
           )
         WHEN MMDD BETWEEN '0101' AND '0229' THEN
           named_struct(
               'startDateOfSeason', date(concat_ws('-', int(YY)-1, '12-01'))
             , 'endDateOfSeason', last_day(concat_ws('-', YY, '02-28'))
             , 'season', 'winter'
             , 'label', (int(YY)-1)*100 + 75
           )
       END AS seasons
       FROM t1
  )
  SELECT itemno
  ,      seasons.*
  ,      sum(totalRequested) AS sum_totalRequestedBySeason
  FROM t2
  GROUP BY itemno, seasons

   """)
```

This will get the following result:

```
df1.show()
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+------+------+--------------------------+
|     itemno|startDateOfSeason|endDateOfSeason|season| label|sum_totalRequestedBySeason|
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+------+------+--------------------------+
|5436134-070|       2013-12-01|     2013-12-31|winter|201375|                       8.0|
|    1824299|       2015-03-01|     2015-05-31|spring|201500|                       1.0|
|    0453978|       2014-09-01|     2014-11-30|autumn|201450|                      18.0|
|    7181584|       2017-01-01|     2017-02-28|winter|201675|                       4.0|
|    7178940|       2014-09-01|     2014-11-30|autumn|201450|                       5.0|
|    7547385|       2014-01-01|     2014-02-28|winter|201375|                      89.0|
|    5814215|       2017-03-01|     2017-05-31|spring|201700|                      35.0|
|    3086317|       2014-09-01|     2014-11-30|autumn|201450|                       1.0|
|    0450636|       2015-01-01|     2015-02-28|winter|201475|                       7.0|
|    2204331|       2015-03-01|     2015-05-31|spring|201500|                       2.0|
|5437474-620|       2015-06-01|     2015-08-31|summer|201525|                       4.0|
|    5133406|       2014-03-01|     2014-05-31|spring|201400|                      46.0|
|    7081417|       2017-03-01|     2017-05-31|spring|201700|                      15.0|
|    7519278|       2013-03-01|     2013-05-31|spring|201300|                      96.0|
|    7558402|       2014-09-01|     2014-11-30|autumn|201450|                     260.0|
|    2204858|       2015-12-01|     2015-12-31|winter|201575|                      34.0|
|5437662-070|       2013-06-01|     2013-08-31|summer|201325|                      78.0|
|    5334160|       2018-01-01|     2018-02-28|winter|201775|                       2.0|
|    3089858|       2014-09-01|     2014-11-30|autumn|201450|                       5.0|
|    7512365|       2014-01-01|     2014-02-28|winter|201375|                     110.0|
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

After we have the season totals, then calculate the sum of the current plus previous 3 seasons using Window aggregate function and then the ratio:

```
df1.selectExpr("*", """

    round(sum_totalRequestedBySeason/sum(sum_totalRequestedBySeason) OVER (         
        PARTITION BY itemno         
        ORDER BY label         
        RANGE BETWEEN 100 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW         
    ),2) AS ratio_of_current_over_current_plus_past_3_seasons

""").show()
```

Comment: ```+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----+--------------+
|     itemno|requestMonth|requestYear|totalRequested|requestDate|MMDD|        season|
+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----+--------------+
|    7512365|           2|       2014|         110.0| 2014-02-01|0201|[2013, winter]|```

Comment: there is data discrepancy because of  ```year(requestDate)-1``` in last line. Pinged here to see if it's mistake or it's there for some logic. Separate question, for previous three seasons, shoulg logic be like ```if current season.season = winter and season.year=2019 then pick autumn, summer and spring from 2018```. Could you please share if there's better way to do it? It feels to me that I am not thinking it properly.

Comment: for 2014, year is coming as 2013 ```date: 2014-02-01 new field: [2013, winter]```

Comment: @SachinSharma, `2014-02-01` is winter from previous year, is this logic right?

Comment: @SachinSharma, I guess Scala treat year strictly than Python does, can you convert all `year(requestDate)` to `int(year(requestDate))` in the SQL?

Comment: I thought you want to start a year form `0301` (or Spring), so that 0201 should be set to the previous year.

Comment: I get what you're saying but season is based off of month and day so if it's between ```1 December to 28 February``` then it's winter season. Year is coming from date. The reason I kept it this way is because it may confuse business end user. They're not correlating season and year and that's why I was confused about ```how to get previous 3 season```. Can you share your logic of how to get previous three seasons? I can hide ```season.year``` at the end, if needed, otherwise business side may get confused.

Comment: ok I think you want to sort by previous three season, then you don't need named season, just label them as 1,2,3,4, for example 201901, 201902, 201903, 201904 that would be easier to handle.

Comment: got it. Can I ask you to update your code for this? I can do it but was asking if it's easy so I can accept and close it till I run into something else. Don't mind this comment if it's too much work.

Comment: for example `WHEN MMDD BETWEEN '0301' AND '0531' THEN CONCAT(year(requestDate), '1')`

Comment: @SachinSharma, have you resolved the data discrepancy issue with `year(requestDate)-1` ?

Comment: yes. I actually did following to add season column . ```val seasonDF = sqlContext.sql("select distinct *, case when month(requestDate) in (3,4,5) then 'Spring' when month(requestDate) in (6,7,8) then 'Summer' when month(requestDate) in (9,10,11) then 'Autumn' when month(requestDate) in (12,1,2) then 'Winter' end as season from temporal order by itemno, requestDate, season")``` where ```temporal is initialDF.createOrReplaceTempView("temporal")```. Now I'll use ```WHEN MMDD BETWEEN '0301' AND '0531' THEN CONCAT(year(requestDate), '1')``` for sorting it out.

Comment: I was wondering if I can use something like ```window and partiton by season and requestYear and use current and 3 preceding``` kind of logic. ```I'll try label logic to solve it.``` Thanks for sharing logic but let me know if window logic makes sense to apply in this case. I am not sure how to implement it though at the moment. working on it...

Comment: @SachinSharma, will need to use RowBetween (by row), not RangeBetween (by offset). in such case, we will need to make sure no season was missing over time period. do something like Pandas df.asfreq()

Comment: or maybe we can set `00` for spring, `25` for summer, `50` for autumn, and `75` for winter and convert this into `integer`, then use the rangeBetween, offset will be 100 for 4 season??

Comment: for example, use `int(year(requestDate))*100` as spring, `int(year(requestDate))*100+25` as summer etc? in such case, rangeBetween should be fine.

Comment: I am trying to solve it with multiple ways, suggested by you, now. Currently, I am working on label logic. There's another issue. Before i share my complicated state in which I am now, can you share how you'll access last 3 seasons using ```concat()... label logic```

Comment: for window function, I've filled missing data with 0 in ```totalRequested Col``` so window should work.

Comment: @SachinSharma, I will merge all in one SQL and update the post in the next few minutes

Comment: @SachinSharma, I ended up doing them separately which is easier to describe. the season column should be integerType so that we can do rangeBetween, no need to fill the missing data in such case.

Comment: BTW. we don't use StringType by CONCAT to construct season column, to use rangeBetween, we will need a numeric column here.

Comment: if you've already fixed the missing seasons, then use `ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` in WindowSpec.

Comment: I am seeing some discrepancy when using 100 preceding logic. I'll update it at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202832/discussion-between-sachin-sharma-and-jxc).